# Understanding Selenium Findelement

Tags: selenium

I want to understand how Findelement works.

**case 1:** Does it act upon the element as soon as it finds in the DOM (before/during the page is loaded & rendered in the browser)

**Case 2:** Or, does it act only when the page has fully loaded & rendered ?

**Case 3:** Or, does it find the element in the DOM (ref. Case 1) and just wait for the page to render so that it can act upon the element now?

Answer (score 0):

FindElement keeps looking for element based on implicit and explicit waits defined in the program.  It will not wait till entire DOM is loaded.

If you want to wait till the page load is complete use pageLoadTimeout:

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Here 10 stands for 10 seconds till TimeoutException is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

- Selenium waits till page will be loaded (`onLoad` event) before
  execution of **any** command (e.g. `get` or
  `find_element_by_css_selector`).
  You can disable this behaviour in
  Firefox:

```py
   from selenium import webdriver

   profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
   profile.set_preference('webdriver.load.strategy', 'unstable')
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

- Using `driver.set_page_load_timeout` you can change the value how long Selenium should wait till page is loaded. If page is not loaded after this amount of time `TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for page load.` will be thrown.
- Implicit and Explicit waits can "change" behaviour of "find element" functionality:
  Read it: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits
  One of the main points: `WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.`
  It means before using Explicit wait if you already set up Implicit wait 'globally' - first what you need to do is disable Implicit wait.

Long story short:
By default "find element" functionality/Selenium waits till page is loaded and trying to find element.